# Extracting more than 1 delimeter on a string

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

After a search of files using FindFirst I got a bunch of files within sub folders. All files arranged in name like

```
D:\Folders\SubFolder\SubSubFolders\FilesName#Category#Phase#Range.dat
```

I want to get the complete location of the files, the name, category, phase dan range and store it in a stringlist. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var List:TStringList;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  ExtractStrings(['#'], [],
    PChar('D:\Folders\SubFolders\SubSubFolders\FileName#Category#Phase#Range.dat'), List);
  ShowMessage(List.Text);
end;
```

This is what I got:

```
D:\Folders\SubFolders\SubSubFolders\FileName
Category
Phase
Range.dat
```

All I want is something like

```
D:\Folders\SubFolders\SubSubFolders\
FileName
Category
Phase
Range.dat
```

Anyone can give me elaboration on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Refined :

Since I cannot find the right way due to Delphi version I use (Delphi 7), I tried the hard way :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Lists:TStringList;    
    s, s_filename, s_directory : string;
begin
  s:= 'D:\Folder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder\FileName#Category#Phase#Range.dat';
  s_directory := ExtractFilePath(s);
  s_filename := ExtractFileName(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s_directory);
  ExtractStrings(['#','.'], [], PChar(s_filename),Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

and got what I want, however, how to insert those strings into array of strings, like the Lists:TStringList, instead of Memo1.Lines? I got an access violation.

Comment: You need a Split function. There are plenty about. A websearch will do it. Many people use TStringList which works fine.

Comment: Never mind, I just forgot to add : Lists := TStringlist.Create;

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify a version, but if you're using XE6 (or the Appmethod equivalent) you can do this:

```
procedure GetFileDetails(const FileName: string; Details: TStrings);
var
  S: string;
begin
  Details.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Details.Clear;
    S := ExtractFilePath(FileName);
    if S <> '' then Details.Add(S);
    Details.AddStrings(FileName.Substring(S.Length).Split(['#']));
  finally
    Details.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

The `string` type (via a helper) got a `Split` method in XE3, but it was a complete dog until XE6.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go straight and short

```
procedure ExtractDetails( const AFilename : string; ADetails : TStrings );
begin
  ADetails.Delimiter := '#';
  // ADetails.StrictDelimiter := True; // AFAIK work not with Delphi 7
  ADetails.DelimitedText := ExtractFileName( AFilename );
  ADetails.Insert( 0, ExtractFilePath( AFilename ) );
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/simplesplitfunction-readingsettingsfromexecutables

```
//Author: steve10120
TStringArray = array of string;

function Split(Expression:string; Delimiter:string):TStringArray;
var
  Res:        TStringArray;
  ResCount:   DWORD;
  dLength:    DWORD;
  StartIndex: DWORD;
  sTemp:      string;
begin
  dLength := Length(Expression);
  StartIndex := 1;
  ResCount := 0;
  repeat
    sTemp := Copy(Expression, StartIndex, Pos(Delimiter, Copy(Expression, StartIndex,     Length(Expression))) - 1);
    SetLength(Res, Length(Res) + 1);
    SetLength(Res[ResCount], Length(sTemp));
    Res[ResCount] := sTemp;
    StartIndex := StartIndex + Length(sTemp) + Length(Delimiter);
    ResCount := ResCount + 1;
  until StartIndex > dLength;
  Result := Res;
end;

var
  Strings:  TStringArray;

begin
  Strings := Split('Good||Morning||World||', '||');
  MessageBox(0, PChar(Strings[2]), nil, 0);
end.
```

Split on \, then Split the last entry on #.